# Global check for valid properties in a PHP stdClass?

Tags: php, stdclass

Is it possible to check properties from a PHP stdClass? I have some models which are being generated as an stdClass. When using them I  would like to check if the properties I'm calling exist in some kind of Core-class. I've noticed __get is ignored by the stdClass...

How can properties from a stdClass be checked if they exist in the object?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean with "__get is ignored by the stdClass", but `__get()` is _not implemented_ in `stdClass`.

Comment: I did'nt knew that. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Comment: If I understand your comments below right: You can also implement `__isset()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StdClass` objects contain only porperties, not code. So you can't code anything from "within" them. So you need to work around this "shortcomming". Depending on what generates these classes this can be done by "overloading" the data (e.g. with a *Decorator*) providing the functionality you've looking for:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $subject;
    public function __construct(object $stdClass)
    {
        $this->subject = $stdClass;
    }
    public function __get($name)
    {
        $exists = isset($this->subject->$name);
        #...
    }
}

$myModel = new MyClass($model);
```

Comment: Yes it's a pattern. If you describe more in your class where and how those `stdClass` objects are created this can be even simplified under certain circumstances.

Comment: This seems like a solution. Thanks! Accepted + 1:)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/get_object_vars) to iterate through the `stdClass` object, then use the [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/property_exists) function to see if the current property exists in the parent class.

Comment: But where to store it globally? Because __get() is ignored..?

Comment: @BenFransen:  Can you post a dump of an instance of stdClass, as well as the Core-class you're referring to.

Comment: the stdClass is generated by mysql_fetch_object(). In a class called System_Core (from which every class extends) there are the magic functions __get() and __set().

Comment: The Decorator pattern is what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it to an array

```
$x = (array) $myStdClassObject;
```

Then you can use all the common array functions

Comment: The goal was actually to have arrays as an object ;)